# Finding the Limit of a function with square roots

Tags: real-analysis, limits

**Question** Determine whether $\lim_{x\rightarrow-2}{\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{6+x}-2}}$ exists, and compute the limit if it exists.

**My Answer** I have taken $f(x)=\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{6+x}-2}=\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{6+x}-2} \frac{\sqrt{6+x}+2}{\sqrt{6+x}+2} = \sqrt{6+x}+2$. Thus $\lim_{x\rightarrow-2}{\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{6+x}-2}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow-2}{\sqrt{6+x}+2}=\sqrt{4}+2$. Here I got confused as $\sqrt{4}= \pm 2$ so the limit is either $4$ or $0$. I don't know if this means that the limit does not exist or if I just take either the positive or negative square root.

Comment: $\sqrt x\ge0$, so $\sqrt4=+2$

Comment: Usually, when we write $\sqrt{x}$, we mean the positive root.  When we have $x^2=4$ is when we could have either the positive or negative root as a solution.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the square root function is taken to mean the positive root.  In other words, $\sqrt{x}\geq 0$ for all $x\geq 0$.  Therefore, if you see a square root in a problem, it is safe to assume that you're looking at the positive root of a number.

The confusion that you're seeing here is that when you have an equation of the form $x^2=4$, for example, you can't just "take the square root of both sides" because that loses solutions.  Since the square root is always positive, taking the square root of both sides only allows $x$ to be positive.

Summarizing so far:

- $\sqrt{x}=2$ has one solution, $x=4$.
- $x^2=4$ has two solutions, $x=2$ and $x=-2$.

One way to look at this difference is that $\sqrt{x}$ is a function from the nonnegative reals to the nonnegative reals while in the question $x^2=4$, you are looking for *all* solutions to the equation.  Taking the square root of both sides gives you one solution, but there are more possibilities.

If we want to be quite technical and more advanced, the $\sqrt{}$ function is choosing a branch of the complex $\sqrt{}$ function and we could chose an alternate branch to get the negative (the cut is along the negative real axis).  Many complex analysis textbooks have two different notations, for example $\sqrt{}$ for the typical square root function and $x^{1/2}$ for a multi-valued square root function.